# jQuery Modal Popup Repeat

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking to implement a jQuery modal popup, a very simple looking one, into my webpage. I would like to use it 5 times on my index page. I've been able to implement it once but when I try to use it again it creates problems with other anchor tags. This is what I have so far.

```
<ul>
  <a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#"><li>Contact</li></a>
  <div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
    <div class="popup-inner">
      <h2 class="form-text">Thanks for contacting!</h2>
      <div id="contact-form">
        <form id="form-input" action="php/contact.php" method="post">
          <label class="form-text">First Name:</label><input class="input-box" type="text" name="sender1" placeholder="First Name" required> <br>
          <label class="form-text">Last Name:</label><input class="input-box" type="text" name="sender2" placeholder="Last Name" required> <br>
          <label class="form-text">Email:</label><input class="input-box" id="input-box" type="senderEmail" name="email" placeholder="Email" required> <br>
          <label class="form-text" id="message">Message:</label><textarea id="message-box" name="message" rows="12" cols="50" placeholder="Please leave a message" required></textarea> <br>
          <input id="submit-button" type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
      </div>
      <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</ul>
```

My jQuery is as follows:

```
$(function() {
    //----- OPEN
    $('[data-popup-open]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-open');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeIn(350);

        e.preventDefault();
    });

    //----- CLOSE
    $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
        $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

My CSS is as follows:

```
/* Outer */
.popup {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

/* Inner */
.popup-inner, popup-inner2 {
    max-width:700px;
    width:90%;
    padding:40px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-radius:3px;
    background:#545454;
}

/* Close Button */
.popup-close {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    padding-top:4px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    transition:ease 0.25s all;
    -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(50%, -50%);
    border-radius:1000px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100%;
    color:#fff;
}

.popup-close:hover {
    -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

The problem I cannot over come is when I try to implement this for another anchor tag it opens up the other anchor tag and they both end up being the same thing. I've attempted changing the class names around to differentiate between the 2 but to no avail. How can I implement this modal popup 5 times over and have it work on the anchor tags it needs to without affecting other anchor tags on the same page.

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/xxc5L188/)

Comment: That's a weird way to use `<ul>`  and `<li>`. Other than that, I can't find anything wrong. Could you make a jsfiddle that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Not just a "weird way" but an incorrect way to use `<ul><li>`. The only tag correct inside a `<ul>` tag is an `<li>` tag. Your anchors and divs are incorrectly placed.

Answer (score 0):

You should just set other data attributes. You did it ok, but I would suggest doing it this way, should make more sense:

```js
$('[data-popup-open]').each(function(i) {
 var thisLink = $(this);
 var popupName = thisLink.data('popupOpen');
 var openPopup = $('[data-popup="'+popupName+'"]');
 thisLink.on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
     openPopup.fadeIn(350);
 });
 $('[data-popup-close="'+popupName+'"]').on('click', function(e) {
  openPopup.fadeOut(350);
 });
});
```

```css
/* Outer */
.popup {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

/* Inner */
.popup-inner, popup-inner2 {
    max-width:700px;
    width:90%;
    padding:40px;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);
    box-shadow:0px 2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,1);
    border-radius:3px;
    background:#545454;
}

/* Close Button */
.popup-close {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    padding-top:4px;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    transition:ease 0.25s all;
    -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%);
    transform:translate(50%, -50%);
    border-radius:1000px;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    font-family:Arial, Sans-Serif;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:100%;
    color:#fff;
}

.popup-close:hover {
    -webkit-transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    transform:translate(50%, -50%) rotate(180deg);
    background:rgba(0,0,0,1);
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
    <a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-1" href="#">Contact</a>
</p>
<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-1">
    <div class="popup-inner">
        <h2 class="form-text">Thanks for contacting!</h2>
        <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">x</a>
    </div>
</div>
<p>
    <a class="btn" data-popup-open="popup-2" href="#">Hallo</a>
</p>
<div class="popup" data-popup="popup-2">
    <div class="popup-inner">
        <h2 class="form-text">How are you doing?</h2>
        <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-2" href="#">x</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also on [Playground](https://jsfiddle.net/gr2dt80f/).

Please note:

1. You should use valid HTML
2. When setting html element data attributes, than you can use it in script this way:

```html
<div id="test" data-height="30"></div>
var t= document.getElementById('test');
console.log( t.dataset.height ); /* Output: 30 */
console.log( $('#test').data('height') ); /* Output: 30 */
```

Please [check this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).